# Rudin theorem 9.21 converse part proof

Tags: real-analysis

Theorem: Suppose f maps an open set $E \subset R^n$ into $R^m$. Then $f \in \mathcal{C'}(E)$ if and only if the partial derivatives $D_j f_i$ exist and are continuous on E for $1 \leq i \leq m, 1 \leq j \leq n$.

For the converse $\text{it suffices to consider the case m=1} \tag 1$
Fix $x \in E$ and $\epsilon >0$, since E is open, there is an open ball $S \subset E$, with center at x and radius r, and the continuity of the functions $D_jf$ shows that r can be chose so that $|(D_jf)(y)-(D_jf)(x)| < \frac{\epsilon}{n} (y \in S, 1 \leq j \leq n)$.

Suppose $h=\sum h_j e_j, |h|<r$, put v_0=0, and $v_k=h_1e_1+...+h_ke_k$, for $1 \leq k \leq n$, then
$$f(x+h)-f(x)=\sum_{j=1}^n [f(x+v_j)-f(x+v_{j-1})] \tag 2$$.

Since $|v_k|<r$ for $1 \leq k \leq n$ and since S is convex, the segments with end points $x+v_{j-1}$ and $x+v_j$ lie in S. Since $v_j=v_{j-1}+h_je_j$, the mean value theorem show that the jth summand in $f(x+h)-f(x)=\sum_{j=1}^n [f(x+v_j)-f(x+v_{j-1})]$ is equal to $$h_j(D_jf)(x+v_{j-1}+\theta_jh_je_j) \tag 3$$ for some $\theta_j \in (0,1)$, and this differs from $h_j(D_jf)(x)$ by less than $|h_j| \epsilon n$, using $|(D_jf)(y)-(D_jf)(x)| < \frac{\epsilon}{n}$. By tag 2, it follows that $$|f(x+h)-f(x)-\sum_{j=1}^n h_j(D_jf)(x)| \leq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n |h_j| \epsilon \leq |h| \epsilon \tag 4$$ for all h such that $|h|<r$. This says that f is differentiable at x and that $f'(x)$ is linear function which assigns the number $\sum h_j(d_jf)(x)$ to the vector $h=\sum h_j e_j$. The matrix $[f'(x)]$ consists of the row $(D_1f)(x),...,(D_nf)(x)$. Since $D_1f,...,D_nf$ sre continuous functions on E, we proved the statement.

I am not sure about the idea of the whole proof, especially those tags, can someone help with explaining? This is Rudin's theorem 9.21 the converse part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove $f$ is differentiable at $x$ you need to show the estimate $|f(x + h) - f(x) - Lh|=o(h)$, as $h \to 0$, for some linear transformation $L: \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R} $.

At (2), he's rewriting $f(x + h) - f(x)$ in a way that there is change in at most one direction(paralell to some axis) at a time. Think of $n=2$, i.e., a rectangle.

At (3) he's merely applying the usual Mean Value Theorem of one variable at each direction.

At (4) he's showing that $L=[\nabla f]$ is the linear transformation we're after.